# Ansible: systemd fails. Which sudo permissions are needed?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.9, Linux Ubuntu 18.

I'm getting the following error with Ansible, when trying to change the status of a service with 'systemd'.

> failed: [host.domain.com] (item=service_1) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "service_1", "module_stderr": "Shared connection to host.domain.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

```
 - name: Stop services
   ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: "{{ serv }}"
    state: stopped
   with_servs:
             - service_1
             - service_2
             - service_3
  become: yes
```

- The code above works fine with an account that has full sudo access (same as root privileges)
- This will fail as shown above with an account having limited sudo access (sudo access to specific commands, such as `/bin/systemctl * service_1*`, `/bin/systemctl * service_2*`, `/bin/systemctl * service_3*`

Which sudo permissions are needed to run ansible.builtin.systemd?  I'm trying to find out what command Ansible sends to the device to check if I gave the right permissions to the account, but no success on finding that yet (any hints?).

Comment: [_You cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε:   This is the solution, thanks. I had to provide full sudo root privileges to the account.

Answer (score 0):

At first change your `with_servs` to `loop:`  ist much easier to writes playbooks with loop. Set `become` as a globall var for playbook. Workaround for this can be exec. a coomand by module `commands` but it's not recomennded because, in every sitatuion it will be executing this commands even when service is stopped.

Comment: Thanks. I put become as global, but it still didn't work. I'm currently assuming that this is a sudo configuration issue perhaps related to the comment from @β.εηοιτ.βε
Also, thanks for the hint to use loop.